# Spring boot application is not running on openWRT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, openwrt, jamvm

I have tried to run a Spring boot microservice application on openWRT, but it causes a runtime exception which is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets`.

jvm used in openWRT is `jamVM v2.0.0` and `java v1.5`.

The exception I am getting is

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.VMMethod.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:327)
   at jamvm.java.lang.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.AsciiBytes.<init>(AsciiBytes.java:51)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<clinit>(JarFile.java:59)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:61)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:57)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:127)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:39)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:36)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
   at java.lang.reflect.VMMethod.invoke(Native Method)
   ...2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets not found in java.lang.ClassLoader$1{urls=[file:/tmp/lan-socks-server-}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:531)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:341)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1112)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:293)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.AsciiBytes.<init>(AsciiBytes.java:51)
```

So the Spring boot is using a `StandardCharsets` class, that is released after `v1.5`.

My application `build.gradle` is

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'lan-socks-server'
    version = "0.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation('io.netty:netty-all:4.1.42.Final')
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5')
}
```

So is there any other jvm support `java 1.8` or how to rectify the issue?

Do I need to right the entire login in core java?

Comment: I love Spring Boot and use it for most of my Web applications... but it's way too heavyweight for the kinds of hardware that run OpenWRT.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will work. I'm not familiar with openWRT, however note that:

1. Spring boot 2.x relies on Spring 5 and therefor requires java 8 at least.
2. Spring boot 1.4.x can run on java 7 and sometimes even on java 6 with [additional configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6) but java 5 is way too old.
3. Side note, if you're planning to use spring boot 2.x it already supports netty by running webflux component for reactive systems (instead of using `spring-boot-starter-web` you can use `spring-boot-starter-webflux`), it will bring netty, no need to specify it explicitly.